# Easy multiple clipboards on linux

Tags: linux, clipboard

I need a feature that will let me have a few clipboards.

Like I have three columns in Calc document. name, surname and phone number.

And I want to copy the name to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and paste it on <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>, and the surname copy from <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> and paste with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> and so on...

Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no easy way to have such a feature, without writing some code of your own, since clipboard behavior depends on the application. Also there is no software (at least for my distro), that implements these shortcuts.

But it is not entirely impossible, albeit a bit hack-y. Here is my idea:

Since you only need three separate clipboards, you're in luck, since there is [technically](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-2.html#s-2.6) three selections in GNU/Linux:

1. `PRIMARY`
2. `SECONDARY`
3. `CLIPBOARD`

While the way they are used is defined by application, you can try force-writing to them. So, for example, if you wold like to occupy `SECONDARY` selection, something like this should do the trick:

```
xsel -o | xsel -s
```

Or for `CLIPBOARD`:

```
xsel -o | xsel -b
```

Now, pasting is a bit more tricky. AFAIK `xsel` and `xclip` can only write the selection to standard output. So, probably, the only option of pasting  would be to overwrite one of the selections. Preferably the `CLIPBOARD` one, so you can simply <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> in Calc.

As for adding actual keyboard shortcuts, that depends on what DE you are using. Typically, keyshorts are located in the system or keyboard settings of most DEs.

Comment: wait, I've opened my keyboard shortcuts and I created new ones

Comment: One I named second clipboard and I gave it command  xsel -o | xsel -s and I gave it a ctrl + d key, second as follows, but it aint working, this isnt copying anything. moreover I'll need to have three different keys to paste. And Im talking about copying it in visual enviroment, not the console to be clear. So you are saying that creating new clipboards isnt that simple matter? Maybe is it possible using some programming language. I am very determined. it would help my workflow and I have some time in my worktime to tamper with it. So please tell me if you have any more hints for me.

Comment: @Mateusz I only tried to give an option to do this without any programming involved. It a flawed method since (as I mentioned above) xsel and xclip can only write the selection to standard output and pasting via ctrl+v is always done from CLIPBOARD selection. If doing a bit of coding yourself is not a problem then it is pretty straightforward from here. With any programming language you're familiar with do a simple script that writes from current selection (output of `xsel -o`) upon your desired keystroke to some buffer or temp file.

Comment: @Mateusz  Pasting on the other hand is still complicated. My best guess would be to just straight up write to clipboard, and always paste with a ctrl+v,. There are other ways ofc, but they would require a LOT more coding, and will still be nothing but pretty rude hacks. But if you feel confidant with the way x11 works, you can try to have the behavior you described above.

Comment: These are just the three pre-defined clipboards / selections. However, you can initiate as many more as you like using any string as identifier. [Have a look](https://www.uninformativ.de/blog/postings/2017-04-02/0/POSTING-en.html)